# Getting a NullPointerException During Initialization of Interface

Tags: java, maven, junit

I write a maven project named "error project". Its aim is to handle exceptions in other projects. It utilizes another maven project "configuration manager". The ultimate aim of configuration manager is to obtain database credentials from some xml files. In this project, it has "IExceptionService", it is proposed that other projects write their exceptions through this interface. This interface's concrete class is assigned at runtime by "DependencyResolver" class. The assignment has been done in "resolve" method as such:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T resolve(Class<T> classType, HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String> parameterMap ) 
{
    try {
        
        if(classType == null)
            throw new ArgumanBosHatasi("classType is null");
        
        if(parameterMap == null)
            throw new ArgumanBosHatasi(HashMap.class.toString());           
        
        assert classType != null : "classType == null";

        if(classType.equals(IErrorRepository.class))            
            return (T)getIErrorRepository();                
        else if(classType.equals(IErrorFile.class))         
            return (T)getIErrorFile();              
        else if(classType.equals(ErrorBusinessRule.class))              
            return (T)getErrorBusinessRule();
        else if(classType.equals(IErrorService.class))
        {
            try {
                 
                return (T)getIErrorService(parameterMap);
                
            } catch (UygulamaHatasi applicationException) {
                throw applicationException;             }                               
        }       
        else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown class type.");
        
    } catch (Exception exception) {
     
        throw exception;            
    }
}
    
private static IErrorRepository getIErrorRepository() {
    
    try 
    {           
        if(errorDatabase != null)
            return errorDatabase;
        
        KonfigurasyonYoneticisi yonetici = new KonfigurasyonYoneticisi();
        
        String sifreKodu = "HATASIFRE";  
        String schema = yonetici.okuAyar("HATASCHEMA");
        String tabloAdi = yonetici.okuAyar("HATATABLOSU");
        String veritabaniUrl = yonetici.okuAyar("HATAVERITABANIURL"); //Here is line 92 in DependencyResolver
        String kullaniciAdi =  yonetici.okuAyar("HATAKULLANICIADI");
        
        if(SozceIsleri.bosMu(sifreKodu))
            throw new BasarisizIslemHatasi("sifreKodu boş geliyor.");
        
        if(SozceIsleri.bosMu(schema))
            throw new BasarisizIslemHatasi("schema boş geliyor.");          

        if(SozceIsleri.bosMu(tabloAdi))
            throw new BasarisizIslemHatasi("tabloAdi boş geliyor.");
        
        if(SozceIsleri.bosMu(veritabaniUrl))
            throw new BasarisizIslemHatasi("veritabaniUrl boş geliyor.");
        
        if(SozceIsleri.bosMu(kullaniciAdi))
            throw new BasarisizIslemHatasi("kullaniciAdi boş geliyor.");
        
        assert SozceIsleri.doluMu(sifreKodu) : "SozceIsleri.bosMu(sifreKodu)";
        assert SozceIsleri.doluMu(schema) : "SozceIsleri.bosMu(schema)";
        assert SozceIsleri.doluMu(tabloAdi) : "SozceIsleri.bosMu(tabloAdi)";
        assert SozceIsleri.doluMu(veritabaniUrl) : "SozceIsleri.bosMu(veritabaniUrl)";
        assert SozceIsleri.doluMu(kullaniciAdi) : "SozceIsleri.bosMu(kullaniciAdi)";            
    
        oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver oracleDriver = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
        
        lock();
        errorDatabase = new HataRepository(oracleDriver, veritabaniUrl,kullaniciAdi,sifreKodu,schema,tabloAdi);
        openLock();
        
        if(errorDatabase == null)
            throw new BosIsaretciHatasi(MesajIsleri.<IErrorRepository>getirBosGeliyorMesaji(IErrorRepository.class));
        
        return errorDatabase;
    
    } catch (BosIsaretciHatasi | BasarisizIslemHatasi hata) {
 
        throw hata;
    
    }finally {          
        openLock();         
    }    
}
```

"DependencyResolverParameter"  is an enum and it only has the value "UYGULAMAANAHTAR". (APPLICATION KEY)

I call this method like that:

```
        int applicationKey = 4;
        
        HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String> map = new HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String>();            
        map.put(DependencyResolverParameter.APPLICATIONKEY, Integer.toString(applicationKey));
        
        IExceptionService service = DependencyResolver.<IExceptionService>resolve(IExceptionService.class, map);
```

I define all necessary dependencies within the project. In the code above, the "service" variable is not null as expected and it writes trial error successfully whenever I write it inside a main method as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int applicationKey = 4;
    
    HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String> map = new HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String>();            
    map.put(DependencyResolverParameter.APPLICATIONKEY, Integer.toString(applicationKey));
    
    IExceptionService servis = DependencyResolver.<IExceptionService>resolve(IExceptionService.class, map);      
    
    System.out.println(String.format("is it null? %b", servis == null));
    
    servis.report(new Exception("trial error. Do not care."));  
}
```

However, when I write the code inside JUnit4 test I am getting "NullPointerException" as below:

```
@Test
public void getHataService_001() {

    try 
    {           
        int applicationKey= 4;
        
        HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String> map = new HashMap<DependencyResolverParameter,String>();            
        map.put(DependencyResolverParameter.APPLICATIONKEY, Integer.toString(applicationKey));
        
        IExceptionService servis = DependencyResolver.<IExceptionService>resolve(IExceptionService.class, map);
        
        assertNotNull(servis);
        
    } catch (Exception exception) {         
        
        fail(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can I solve that problem? Thanks in advance.
From the stacktrace, I deduce that there is a problem of reading settings from configuration class.

junit dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

***stacktrace:***

```
m:java.lang.NullPointerExceptionlm:nullst:hata.businesslayer.dependencyresolvers.DependencyResolver.resolve(DependencyResolver.java:92)
kisi.core.crosscuttingconcern.exceptionhandling.HataIsleri.getHataService(HataIsleri.java:229)
kisi.core.crosscuttingconcern.exceptionhandling.HataIsleri.raporlaHata(HataIsleri.java:75)
test.hata.HataServisTesti.getHataService_001(HataServisTesti.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

2020/07/09 14:41:34
m:java.lang.NullPointerException
lm:nullst:hata.businesslayer.dependencyresolvers.DependencyResolver.resolve(DependencyResolver.java:92)
test.hata.HataServisTesti.getHataService_001(HataServisTesti.java:56)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)2020/07/09 14:41:34
```

Comment: it is not possible for this code to compile. Please provide your actual code

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: because your resolve method has a return statement that can not be reached. either it returned the value from the if block, or it threw the exception of the else block, but it can't reach the return null. No doubt your compiler would have told you this, had you tried to compile it

Comment: can you share stack trace

Comment: I will make necessary additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of an apache maven project inside a project. When I remove the apache maven project, it works.